# Confirmation button before executing Django Admin action?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've really been enjoying using and modifying the Django admin interface recently!

Is there a "Django Way" method of adding some kind of confirmation action or button at the bottom of the admin page, before executing the action? Right now it executes as soon as you select the action.

Some of the actions we may want to execute against the production DB could be destructive, and a basic confirmation button would go a long way to preventing human error as we roll out the product - for example, prevent ourselves from accidentally hitting the "Delete" dropdown on a bunch of important rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Delete already has a confirmation.

Comment: @brandon - Ok, so is there a way of replicating that confirmation for custom commands?

Comment: You can always add a custom view to admin.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation provides insight into creating intermediate pages for custom actions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages).